# Automapping Dictionary

Tags: c#

I am trying to automap a dictionary to another without replacing existing values with null but just update them with the new ones if necessary. However i can't get it to work anyway.

Code :

```
class Klass
{
    public Dictionary<string, string[]> Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
}

class Main
{
    private Klass ex1 = new Klass();

    public Main()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Klass, Klass>().ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(srs => !srs.IsSourceValueNull));

        TestRun("1");
        TestRun("2");
        TestRun("3");
        //EVERY CALL REPLACES THE OTHER HERE IDK WHY [OTHER MAPPER VALUES I MEAN]

    }

    public void TestRun(string text)
    {
        var ex2 = new Klass();
        ex2.Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string[]>
        {
            {text, new []{"1", "2... etc as provided"}}
        };
        Mapper.Map(ex2, ex1);
    }
}
```

Comment: @COLDTOLD: The supposed result i am waiting is after i call those 3 methods the ex1 class's Dictionary loaded with three values!

Comment: none of your values are null ???

Comment: Nope!, As stated in the thread i just want the automapper to fill on the ex1 class's dictionary with any new values and if a value exists already just update it. However it just adds wipes the older dictionary every time the method is called then adds the new one so i get the old values deleted.

Comment: @COLDTOLD: Meaning that the whole dictionary is being replaced instead of just replacing/adding it's values.!

Comment: If that all you want to do and your property is just a dictionary you have I would not use automapper I would just write a small dynamic method to do it I am not sure if what you wnat is possible with automapper

Comment: And the reason i want to stick to automapper is that it maps a lot of other values not mentioned in the thread to avoid complexity.